# Ориентиры в определении сроков разработки и рефакторинга веб-проектов

Tags: проектирование, рефакторинг

Встала задача поддерживать сайт, который писался много лет и представляет собой лютый говнокод. Ни документации, ни комментариев нет. О форматировании автор не слышал. Зато есть острое желание владельцев сайта понаделать заплаток там, где - *на их взгляд* - самые проблемные места.

В ближайшее время предстоит разговор о сроках работы и мне хотелось бы **отталкиваться не от компромиссов** (типа такого: *я думаю, что у меня уйдет полгода только на минимально необходимую ревизию кода, заказчик думает, что надо все сделать за неделю => договорились на три месяца*), **а от объективных ориентиров**.

**Пример для затравки (цифры условные).** Общий объем кода - 50 тыс. строк кода. В день я могу написать 50 строк нормального, покрытого тестами и документированного кода. Отсюда имеем 50000/50 = 1000 трудодней = 200 недель = 3 года 10 месяцев работы одного программиста (без учета отпусков и праздников).

Примерно такие **объективные ориентиры в оценке времени анализа/рефакторинга/создания веб-приложения** хотелось бы услышать. Ну и логика оценки тоже будет крайне интересна.

Comment: Хм.

Я бы на вашем месте просто отказался от задания: чужой говнокод _гораздо_ легче переписать с нуля, чем поддерживать. Я бы постарался объяснить владельцам сайта, что они видят лишь вершину айсберга, что их codebase — карточный домик, «подклеишь нос — отвалится хвост».

Объективно оценить время на разработку **до того, как вы просмотрели и поняли хотя бы костяк кода** — нереально и бесперспективно. Потребуйте (оплаченное) время на разбор и оценку.

Если вы фрилансер, тогда всё, конечно, хуже. Я бы не брался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ответ интересен чисто теоретически, есть такая метрика как [цикломатическая сложность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D6%E8%EA%EB%EE%EC%E0%F2%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E0%FF_%F1%EB%EE%E6%ED%EE%F1%F2%FC), которую вполне можно измерить. Вполне вероятно есть еще какие-то.

Еще видел [статью на хабре с размышлениями на эту тему](http://habrahabr.ru/post/205342/)